# Passing PHP array to jQuery returns empty array or notice

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm trying to read some information from a MySQL database using php and then pass the results to jquery and log them in the console.

To read from the database I use:

```
public function getQuestions(){
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM Question';
    $statement = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $questions = [];
    while($row = $statement->fetch()){
        $questions[] = array(
            'QuestionID' => $row['QuestionID'],
            'Content' => $row['QuestionContent']
        );
    }
    return $questions;
}
```

where `$this->db` is a PDO object.

Then this method is called from

```
<?php

include_once 'classes/DatabaseAdapter.php';

$dba = new DatabaseAdapter();
echo $dba->getQuestions(); // Array to String conversion error.
```

And that is then called from jQuery with:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'questions.php',
    method: 'post'
}).done(function(data){
    console.log('done');
    console.log(data);
});
```

The problem I'm having is when I encode the output as json in PHP with `json_encode()` I get an empty string in the console and decode it in jQuery with `JSON.parse()`. Then I try passing it without encoding and get a notice saying Array to String conversion in PHP line with `echo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way. You can adapt the code to your `getQuestions()` function

**Php code**

```
//PDO connection

$host   = "";
$user   = "";
$dbname = "";
$pass   = "";

try {
  $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8", $user, $pass,
                    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
}

//PDO Database query and Json encode

$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM Question");
$STH->execute();
$result = $STH->fetchAll();
$data = array();
$data['items'] = $result;
echo json_encode($data);
```

**Jquery**

```
//$.getJSON is a shorthand Ajax function

$.getJSON("questions.php", function(data) {
console.log(data);
$.each(data.items, function(i, value){
console.log(value.thecolumnnameinmysqltable);
})
})
```

In the Php im creating an array for the purpose that you can add extra data and retrieve it .eg

```
$data = array();
$data['data'] = array("one", "two", "three", "four");
$data['items'] = $result;
echo json_encode($data);
```

and to retrieve the $data['data'] array in Jquery you do

```
    var one   = data.data[0];
    var two   = data.data[1];
    var three = data.data[2];
    var four  = data.data[3];
```

Getjson info -- http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: Tried that and id doesn't print anything on the console.

Comment: @DidierFuentes -- Do you get any errors in the PHP/Apache error log file??

Comment: The only thing that is relevant to this case (as far as I understand) is this error in the php_error_log `[05-Jun-2015 16:07:54 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\SurveyTest-php\questions.php on line 10` And that would be where I echo the result/array

Comment: @DidierFuentes  -- that method definetly works, as im usimg it in an app. However because you wrapped it in a function and call from somewere else  did you try ( return  json_encode($data); ) instead of ( echo json_encode($data); ) in the function

Comment: Your answer worked! Problem in the end was I assumed the encoding was UTF-8 because that's the database default. But adding the last parameter to PDO constructor returned the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
echo json_encode($dba->getQuestions());
exit;
```

Comment: Still get empty string.

Comment: $dba->getQuestions() is array return.
i hope u check array is print.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: It printed the actual structure of the array with the content I need.

Comment: this method return data u need.??

Comment: Yes, it has the data. But, can I use it from there? I tried `json_encode`ing it and it returned empty again.